# How to export Firebase Auth users, including providerUserInfo for Sign In with Apple users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I want to export all the users inside of Firebase Auth because I want to migrate away from Firebase. I can get the export of the users just fine with the command:

```
firebase auth:export users.json --format=json --project [my-project]
```

However, for all of the users that use Sign In with Apple the `providerUserInfo` is an empty array, so there is currently no way at all to import them into my own database and keep them as functional accounts that can actually login via SIWA again.

When I look at the auth user by adding an `onAuthStateChanged` listener and logging the auth user to the console, then `providerData.uid` is Apple's user id, the exact ID that I need to copy to my new database:

```js
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, authUser => {
    if (authUser) {
      const uid = authUser.providerData[0].uid;
      if (authUser.providerData[0].providerId === "apple.com") {
        console.log(`Apple ID: ${uid}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Email address: ${uid}`);
      }
    }
  });
```

So the value is definitely stored in Firebase Auth, and it's this value that I need to be able to export for all users.

So my question is: how can I fetch the `providerUserInfo` for such users? Would the `accounts:lookup` REST endpoint help? Sadly I can't really figure out how that endpoint is supposed to work, what the `idToken` you need to send is supposed to be.

Comment: I guess one way is to utilize `onAuthStateChanged` and store `providerData.uid` in a different collection, but a) that is a big security risk, letting the client create such documents and b) I'd need to force all users to use the site before completing my migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to export all the users, including Apple's internal user id, by using the admin SDK:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const records = {};

function handleUser(userRecord) {
  records[userRecord.uid] = userRecord;
}

const listAllUsers = nextPageToken => {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  return admin
    .auth()
    .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(listUsersResult => {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(userRecord => {
        handleUser(userRecord);
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        return listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
};

// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
listAllUsers().then(() => {
  const data = JSON.stringify(records);

  fs.writeFile("users.json", data, err => {
    console.log("JSON data is saved.");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ProviderUserInfo includes the following data:

```
{
  displayName?: string,
  email: string,
  phoneNumber?: string,
  photoURL?: string,
  providerId: string,
  uid: string
}
```

For SIWA (Sign In with Apple) users, their information is anonymized and you must gain explicit consent from the user to be able to collect their personal information. If you had such information you would use `updateProfile()` to attach it to their user ID at the top of their `UserRecord`. If there were a `ProviderUserInfo` entry for Apple, it would consist of:

```
{
  displayName: null,    // SIWA does not provide a display name
  email: string,        // an anonymized email, same as User.email
  phoneNumber: null,    // SIWA does not provide a phone number
  photoURL: null,       // SIWA does not provide profile images  ​
 ​ providerId: string,   // "apple"
 ​ uid: string           // same as User.localId
}
```

As the available data is found elsewhere, it is pointless to include in the response and is omitted.

Transferring SIWA users is not a straightforward process. You must follow the steps outlined in the [Transferring apps and users to new teams](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/bringing_new_apps_and_users_into_your_team) documentation. In short, you use a "Transfer ID Token" with a freshly signed in user's account details, to ask Apple's auth service "Did this user ever sign in for this old client ID?". The returned response will then either say "Yes, their ID with the old client ID was X" or "No, this is a new user". Based on that you migrate their old data across to your new database and authentication ID.

Importantly, after 60 days, you can no longer transfer users from the old service to the new one.

Comment: I don’t really understand. Internally Firebase Auth must store Apple’s user id somewhere, to link an Auth user to an Apple user. The `sub` value of Apple’s JWT. If I could export that value, then the users can login on the new database as if nothing happened.

Comment: Actually when I look at the auth user (add a `onAuthStateChanged` listener and console log the auth user), then `providerData.uid` is most definitely Apple's user id, the exact ID that I need to copy to my new database. So the value is definitely stored in Firebase Auth, and it's this value that I need to be able to export for all users.